# XPages: Javascript library rendered as escaped characters

Tags: xpages

I have a JavaScript library that is rendered as escaped characters instead of accented characters:

```
if (titre == "Directeur G\u00E9n\u00E9ral / VP / Pr\u00E9sident") {...
```

instead of :

```
if (titre == "Directeur Général / VP / Président") {...
```

I am using Notes 9.0.9FP9 and IE11 (does the sasmething in Chrome).

Any ideas why?  It seems all JS librairies have the same behavior so I'm guessing it's a database setting somewhere???

: )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set "UTF-8" in preferences

- "General / Workspace"

  [image]
- and in project preferences "Recourse"

  [image]